# How to design the architecture to achieve proper data separation in Redis and not produce dozens of Redis instances and be able to scale

Tags: architecture, redis

I am working on a huge enterprise project with 5 sub-projects - considered a separate apps. To make it simple two are APIs  delivering data, three other consume them and interact with users. They do not share the same cache. APIs would mostly cache the queries and parsed/transformed XMLs while consumers would mostly cache API calls and user related data.

Each of the API projects has 5 environments, and each consumer has 4 environments. 2*5+3*4 = 22 environments together.

Currently all of them use separate memcached services (so 22).

We consider/plan to move to Redis as a caching platform and we were thinking about Redis Cluster, but we would also like to have a good data separation. Having 22 clusters, for each project/environment, doesn't seem to be the right option.

What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

You can set up only one redis cluster, and use different key prefixes to isolate keys for different projects, I.e. create a namespace for each project.

For example, all keys of the first environment of the first API project have a key prefix: `api1:env1:` (e.g. `api1:env1:key1`, `api1:env1:key2`); all keys of the second environment of the second API project have a key prefix: `api2:env2:` (e.g. `api2:env2:key1`, `api2:env2:key2`); for all keys of the first environment of the first consumer have a key prefix: `con1:env1:`, and so on.

In this way, all data of different environments of different projects can be saved in one redis cluster.

Comment: Vote from me but looking for some alternatives as I would like some "stronger" separation constraint than, assume that is what you suggest, on the client level. Teams responsible for each sub-project may try to stick to that namespacing/prefixing convention, but I would like to avoid a situation that one of them could accidently impact on others.

Comment: @jakubwrona You might need to implement a proxy, which adds key prefix automatically based on the environment and project, and talk to redis cluster. For example, request from client to proxy: *set key val env1 proj1*, request from proxy to redis cluster: *set env1:proj1:key val*. Since any request to proxy must contain *env* and *proj*, teams won't accidentally impact others.

Comment: and how about flushing all keys from a given proj, env? The only way I could think about it would be with tagging, am I right? And then there would need to be some logic on the proxy level...

Comment: In fact, the proxy can be a light-weight library, which wraps all key-prefix work, and expose a new interface. Ask your team members to access Redis cluster only with the new interface with proj, env and version info.

Comment: @jakubwrona  Yes, you can have a third prefix for the key: *version*, i.e. `api1:env1:ver1:key1`. When you want to do the flush, just use a new version number for the given <proj, env>. The proxy doesn't need to manage the version info, it only asks user to pass in a new parameter: *version number*, and build the key prefix with it. Since you take Redis as a cache, and you'll set an expire time for each key, those keys of old version will vanish in the near future. You don 't need to flush them explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

If you need data isolation and want a single instance to handle it, then Redis is not a viable solution for you.

There is no enforced isolation between Redis "databases" as any app could use the `select` command to switch to another one. Further all persistence is saved to the same file so you lose the limited namespacing with persistence.

Aside from data isolation there are also no way to ensure app A can't affect app B. Any issuance of a `flushall` on any DB will destroy all data on the server. Conversely one app could consume all of the memory available, causing the others to lose write ability.  Going further, any single app can lock the entire Redis server.

If you have multiple apps with   no risk of them accidentally affecting each other, and want to use Redis you will need dedicated instances, preferably with different passwords on each.

That type of setup isn't complicated and doesn't require cluster, but is off-topic for SO. It would be a lot less effort than essentially writing a big piece of middleware to try to create all of the various and sundry niggly bits between apps and Redis.